# How to write Spec tests for routes - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to write a test for `SessionsController` and I wrote the following:

I'm using Spec 3.3

```
    RSpec.describe SessionsController, type: :controller do

        describe SessionsController do

            describe "POST create" do 

                it "sign in should have a valid route" do
                    post('/api/signin').should route_to('api/sessions#create')
                end

            end

        end

    end
```

This app is to work mostly as an API, so for now, there's no need for views.

In my routes I have the following:

```
match     '/api/signin',                          to: 'api/sessions#create',
```

Yet the test is not passing.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT: The errors:**

```
rspec ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:27 # SessionsController SessionsController POST create sign in should have a valid route
rspec ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:31 # SessionsController SessionsController POST create creates a new session
```

**EDIT2: Added full test code**

Comment: what error message are you receiving?

Comment: I've edited my question to include the error I'm getting. Its basically just saying the test is failing.

Comment: It depends on the RSpec version you are using but couldn't it be that you are missing to specify the test type `:type => :controller` ?

Comment: I don't get why the down vote. What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify `type: :routing` and use [assert_routing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html#method-i-assert_routing) which has the benefice to test your route in 2 ways (route generation and route matching)

I make my answer general, so other people can take info from it, please adapt to your case

```
describe MyController, type: :routing do
  it 'routing' do
    # This is optional, but also a good reminder to tell me when I add a route
    #   and forgot to update my specs.
    #   Please see bellow for the helper definition
    expect(number_of_routes_for('my_controller')).to eq(8)

    # Then test for the routes, one by one
    assert_routing({method: :get, path: '/my_controller'},   {controller: 'my_controller', action: 'index'})
    assert_routing({method: :get, path: '/my_controller/1'}, {controller: 'my_controller', action: 'show', id: '1'})
    # ... And so on, for each route
  end
end
```

**Note**: If get errors with `assert_routing` (I guess it will be the case with `match`, but I can't remember) then have a look at [assert_generates](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html#method-i-assert_generates) and [assert_recognizes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html#method-i-assert_recognizes)

---

And the `number_of_routes_for` helper

```
def number_of_routes_for(controller)
  Rails.application.routes.routes.to_a.select{ |r| r.defaults[:controller] == controller }.count
end
```